# wait for shell script and then call a new command

Tags: shell

i'm newbie with sheel script. I need help creating a script to shut down all firefox processes, wait a few seconds and then call firefox again. I plan to use CRON scheduling.

I tried to do the following, I created the killFirefox.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash

killFirefox() {   
    pkill -9 -f firefox   
    sleep 10   
    return 0 
}

killFirefox
```

and on crontab I put the following:

```
*/1 * * * * /home/funcionario/killFirefox.sh &&  export DISPLAY=:0 && firefox -kiosk http://rh.minuano.com.br
```

I believe the problem is in returning TRUE after running the killFirefox.sh script. Any idea?

Comment: You're really doing this every minute?

Comment: What _is_ the problem? I think you forgot to describe that.

Comment: this will happen every 3 hours. I left it every minute just so I could test it.

Comment: So, what happens? What should have happened?